# Tsung. contents_from_file attribute with variable value

Tags: performance, scalability, benchmarking, load-testing, tsung

I've got a problem using tsung:

I've got several files in one dir wich I have to send to the server. I
create file with list of this files (fullpath) and add an option to
tsung config:

```
 <option name="file_server" id="xml_files" value="/home/ubuntu/.tsung/files"></option>
```

My goal is to pick a random filepath from this file and send to the
server. To do so I wrote this part of config:

```
  <setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="xml_files" delimiter=";"
order="random">
       <var name="file_name" />
     </setdynvars>

     <request subst="true">
           <http url="/" version="1.1" method="POST"
contents_from_file="%%_file_name%%"></http>
     </request>
```

But this do not work. When I set attr contents_from_file as constant
everything works fine.
Is there any way to do this with variable?

Comment: FWIW, this is not possible (yet.)
I've created a ticket at https://support.process-one.net/browse/TSUN-233

Answer (score 3):

I got the similar thing working, i am using tsung 1.5.0. you may want to try:

```
<request subst="true">
           <http url="/" version="1.1" method="POST"
contents="%%readafile:readrnd%%"></http>
     </request>
```

where readfafile is your own module that exports readrnd function.
readrnd should return contents of random file.
Note : filename would be a binary when read from file source, you may have to serialize.

instead of:

```
<request subst="true">
           <http url="/" version="1.1" method="POST"
contents_from_file="%%_file_name%%"></http>
     </request>
```